# Angular refresh data in child component from filtered value

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a reusable child table component that loads dynamically based on data from the parent component.

For the first time everything loads well, however when I need to click on one of the sort columns in the table I need to send that sort property again to the parent component to return the result from api and refresh the data in the child component with a new set of data from api.

In the code it looks like this, I missed something in that refresh:

**table.component.ts**

```
export class TableComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() items;
  @Input() headers;

  @Input('sortColumn') sortColumn;
  @Output() sortColumnChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.items;
    console.log('OnChanges', changes);
  }

    onSortClick(event, selectedColumn) {
const target = event.currentTarget,
  classList = target.classList;

let column = '';

if (classList.contains('sort-icon-asc')) {
  classList.remove('sort-icon-asc');
  classList.add('sort-icon-desc');
  column = `${selectedColumn} DESC`;
  this.sortColumn = column;
  this.sortColumnChange.emit(column);
} else {
  classList.add('sort-icon-asc');
  classList.remove('sort-icon-desc');
  column = `${selectedColumn} ASC`;
  this.sortColumn = column;
  this.sortColumnChange.emit(column);
}
```

}
}

**table.component.html**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <td (click)="onSortClick($event, header.value)" *ngFor="let header of headers" class="sort-icon-asc">{{ header.name }}</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>  
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
      <td *ngFor="let value of item | objectValues">
        {{ value }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**users.component.ts**

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  observablesDispose$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  sortColumn = 'userId ASC';
  items: [];
  usersTableHeaders = [
    {
      value: 'userId',
      name: this.translateService.instant('ADMIN.USERS_TABLE.USER_ID')
    },
    {
      value: 'name',
      name: this.translateService.instant('ADMIN.USERS_TABLE.NAME')
    },
    {
      value: 'role',
      name: this.translateService.instant('ADMIN.USERS_TABLE.ROLE')
    },
    {
      value: 'email',
      name: this.translateService.instant('ADMIN.USERS_TABLE.EMAIL')
    },
    {
      value: 'status',
      name: this.translateService.instant('ADMIN.USERS_TABLE.STATUS')
    }
  ];

  constructor(
    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
    private readonly translateService: TranslateService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers(): void {
    this.usersService
      .getUsers(this.sortColumn)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.observablesDispose$))
      .subscribe((users) => {
        this.items = users.resultList.map((tableColumn) => ({
          userId: tableColumn.userId,
          name: tableColumn.displayName,
          role: tableColumn.role,
          email: tableColumn.email,
          status: tableColumn.status
        }));
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.observablesDispose$.next();
    this.observablesDispose$.complete();
  }
}
```

**users.component.html**

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="table-section">
    <app-table
      [headers]="usersTableHeaders"
      [items]="items"
      [(sortColumn)]="sortColumn">
    </app-table> 
  </div>
  </div>
```

**EDIT**

**users.component.ts**

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  observablesDispose$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  sortColumn = 'userId ASC';
  items: [];
  usersTableHeaders = [
    {
      value: 'userId',
      name: this.translateService.instant('ADMIN.USERS_TABLE.USER_ID')
    },
    {
      value: 'name',
      name: this.translateService.instant('ADMIN.USERS_TABLE.NAME')
    },
    {
      value: 'role',
      name: this.translateService.instant('ADMIN.USERS_TABLE.ROLE')
    },
    {
      value: 'email',
      name: this.translateService.instant('ADMIN.USERS_TABLE.EMAIL')
    },
    {
      value: 'status',
      name: this.translateService.instant('ADMIN.USERS_TABLE.STATUS')
    }
  ];

  constructor(
    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
    private readonly translateService: TranslateService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers(): void {
    this.usersService
      .getUsers(this.sortColumn)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.observablesDispose$))
      .subscribe((users) => {
        this.items = users.resultList.map((tableColumn) => ({
          userId: tableColumn.userId,
          name: tableColumn.displayName,
          role: tableColumn.role,
          email: tableColumn.email,
          status: tableColumn.status
        }));
      });
  }

updateSort(newColumn: string): void {
    this.sortColumn = newColumn;
    this.getUsers();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.observablesDispose$.next();
    this.observablesDispose$.complete();
  }
}
```

**users.component.html**

```
     <div class="row">
  <div class="table-section">
    <app-table
      [headers]="usersTableHeaders"
      [items]="items"
      [(sortColumn)]="sortColumn"
      (sortColumnChange)="updateSort($event)"
    >
    </app-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your way of handle `sortColumn` change you cannot control change of it to update users list. In your component you should do like:

**users.component.html**

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="table-section">
    <app-table
      [headers]="usersTableHeaders"
      [items]="items"
      [sortColumn]="sortColumn"
      (sortColumnChange)="updateSort($event)">
    </app-table> 
  </div>
  </div>
```

**users.component.ts**

```js
...

updateSort(newColumn: string): void {
    this.sortColumn = newColumn;
    getUsers();
}
```

Comment: Perfect..it's working. I assumed I was missing another refresh trigger. Thanks so much @Ilia